# Update (ado) recordset with sql reserved word as a column

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, ado, recordset, reserved-words

I am executing the following code:

```
Set cmdTemp = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmdTemp.CommandType = adCmdText
...
cmdTemp.CommandText = "SELECT email, [Identity], UserName, UserId " & _
                      "  FROM Users WHERE UserId = '" & UserId & "'"

rst.Open cmdTemp, ,adOpenForwardOnly ,adLockOptimistic
rst("Identity") = "101" //ERROR!
rst.Update
rst.Close
```

It gives this error:

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1'
>
> Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested
>   name or ordinal.
>
> /iweb/admin/Users.asp, line 2118

I understand is because the word Identity is reserved in SQL server, but just can't get this to work.

Also tried to replace the line that is throwing the error for:

```
rst("[Identity]") = "101"
```

And the result is:

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1'
>
> Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested
>   name or ordinal.
>
> /iweb/admin/Users.asp, line 2118

Comment: So `[Identity]` is your table column name here ?

Comment: Looks like line 2118 is raising the error.  Which line is this?  Suspect it'll be *rst("Identity") = "101"* or *cmdTemp.CommandText = "SELECT ...*.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana, Yes it is and I am not able to change its name, which I also consider is the best option.

Comment: @destination-data, you are correct.

Comment: @DanielV: I think because of this line you get the error. `rst.Open cmdTemp, ,adOpenForwardOnly ,adLockOptimistic`. Just remove extra comma near `cmdTemp`.

Comment: Try changing *rst("Identity")* to *rst("[Identity]")*.  If that doesn't work you can use *rst.Fields(1).Name* to find what it is called in the resultset.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana that is not correct [Open Method (ADO Recordset)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544(v=vs.85).aspx) that space is for the active connection which I am not including on purpose.

Comment: @DanielV: Is there any record exists in the table with your passing parameter Userid ? Because it looks like there is no any record for the userid that you pass.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana yes they are.

Comment: Could you use rst(1) = "101"

Comment: @SteveFord It is not possible until I change the parameters in the Open method as indicated in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try open the recordset with `adOpenKeyset` `CursorTypeEnum`

Look for example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676116%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: You are correct, this is solving the issue, changing the Open parameters to:

`rst.Open cmdTemp, , adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic`

I am able to use:

`rst("identity") = identity`

Thank you!

Comment: @DanielV May the force be with us all.   ;-D